# how to change an old commit to become a fixup commit

Tags: git

I have list of commits:

```
1a First commit
2b Second commit 
3c Third commit
4d fixup! First Commit
5e fixup! Second Commit
6f fixup! Third Commit
HEAD 6f
```

I want to be able to change a commit in the past to become a fixup, and in some cases I want to redirect all fixup! pointing to that commit to point to the new fixup! commit

say.

```
1a First commit
2b Second commit 
3c fixup! First Commit
4d fixup! First Commit
5e fixup! Second Commit
6f fixup! First Commit
```

Comment: Have you pushed this local repository to any remote repository? If so, are others using it to collaborate or is it only yours? This matters because changing commit history on a remote can be destructive.

Comment: @BrianaSwift to me i think changing one commit is as destructive as changing many. If its under consent of the team to come up with a cleaner history that people actually bother to look at, e.g. merging relevant commits, I think its for the best of git : ), and yes, this is a decision made by members of a committed under a regiment of direct democracy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you want to keep these commits marked as `fixup!`:

  Use `git rebase -i` and change `pick 3c Third commit` to `reword 3c Third commit`. You will also need to restore the order and operations of the commits marked with `fixup!` if `autosquash` is enabled in your configuration.
- If you don't want to just convert `3c` to `fixup!`, but you also want to apply the fix-ups as amends to the corresponding commits:

  Use `git rebase -i --autosquash` and change `pick 3c Third commit` to `fixup 3c Third commit` and move it up to right after the `pick 1a First commit`. The other commits will already be reordered.

Comment: Note that you can run `git rebase -i --no-autosquash` to override your current configuration.

Comment: You mean change `pick 3c Third commit` to `reword 3c !fixup First commit` right?